# What is the best way to delete an image in Cloudinary Using PHP?

Tags: image, cdn, cloudinary

I'm fairly new to Cloudinary and programming in general.

I'm integrating Cloudinary Image CDN to an app I am creating and would like to know what is the difference in using "`\Cloudinary\Uploader::destroy('zombie');`" vs "`$api->delete_resources('zombie');`".

Is their a speed advantage by using one over the other or is their a certain use scenario for them?

Your responses are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `destroy` method supports a single-file deletion and isn't rate limited.
The `delete_resources` is an Admin API method which supports bulk deletions but is rate limited.